# GSheet - Sort Data : How to SORT data in GSheet?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

Problem goes as follows - Have a GSheet with four different columns. Name is associated with unique links and time.

| Name | Link 0A | Link 0B | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Link 01 | Link 11 | 03:00 PM |
| Second | Link 02 | Link 12 | 01:00 PM |
| Third | Link 03 | Link 13 | 05:00 PM |
| Fourth | Link 04 | Link 14 | 11:00 AM |
| Fifth | Link 05 | Link 15 | 02:00 PM |
| Sixth | Link 06 | Link 16 | 10:00 AM |

Just looking for a solution where a command can arrange the whole data into ascending or descending order according to Time.

**Solution would be like this -**

| Name | Link 0A | Link 0B | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sixth | Link 06 | Link 16 | 10:00 AM |
| Fourth | Link 04 | Link 14 | 11:00 AM |
| Second | Link 02 | Link 12 | 01:00 PM |
| Fifth | Link 05 | Link 15 | 02:00 PM |
| First | Link 01 | Link 11 | 03:00 PM |
| Third | Link 03 | Link 13 | 05:00 PM |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is in `Sheet1!A1:D`:

If you want to sort the data in place permanently, choose **View > Freeze > 1 row**, click cell `D1` and choose **Data > Sort sheet by column D, A → Z**.

If you want *show* the data in another sheet in sorted order, use a `query()` formula like this:

`=query(Sheet1!A1:D, "where A is not null order by D asc", 1)`

To sort in descending order, replace `asc` with `desc`.

The `query()` function will reproduce static links like `https://www.x.org/` fine, but will convert `hyperlink()` formulas and links created with **Insert > Link** to text. If your links are of those types, use `sort()` instead, like this:

`=sort(Sheet1!A2:D, Sheet1!D2:D, true)`

To sort in descending order, replace `true` with `false`.